# OpenGL ES 3.0 - Textures black

Tags: java, android, opengl-es, textures, opengl-es-3.0

I try to render a simple texture .png on a square but it appear always black.
In my sample code are 2 squares rendered, one with a texture wall.png and the second with a 4 pixel bytebuffer for testing.
I checked some pixels and size of the bitmap, they are ok.
The 4 pixel bytebuffer is working, but with a strange failure.
The bytebuffer require 2 extra bytes of data, I have no idea what can cause this.

Thanks for your help!!!

```
    package com.example.opengles3_test1;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.opengl.GLES30;
import android.opengl.GLSurfaceView;
import android.util.Log;

import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.ByteOrder;
import java.nio.FloatBuffer;
import java.nio.ShortBuffer;

import javax.microedition.khronos.egl.EGLConfig;
import javax.microedition.khronos.opengles.GL10;

public class Renderer_Texture implements GLSurfaceView.Renderer {
    private static String TAG = "Renderer"; //For LOG
    final int VERTEX_POS_SIZE = 3; // x, y and z
    final int VERTEX_COLOR_SIZE = 4; // r, g, b, and a
    final int VERTEX_TEXTUR_SIZE=2; //x,y
    final int VERTEX_POS_INDX = 0;
    final int VERTEX_COLOR_INDX = 1;
    final int VERTEX_TEXTUR_INDX = 2;
    final int VERTEX_STRIDE = (4 * (VERTEX_POS_SIZE + VERTEX_COLOR_SIZE+VERTEX_TEXTUR_SIZE));
    // 3 vertices, with (x,y,z) ,(r, g, b, a), (x,y) per-vertex
    final int[] textures = new int[2];
    private final float[] mVerticesData =
            {
            // positions          // colors           // texture coords
            -0.1f,  0.4f, 0.0f,   1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,  1.0f, 1.0f, // top right
            -0.1f, -0.4f, 0.0f,   0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,  1.0f, 0.0f, // bottom right
            -0.8f, -0.4f, 0.0f,   0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,  0.0f, 0.0f, // bottom left
            -0.8f,  0.4f, 0.0f,   1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,  0.0f, 1.0f  // top left

            };
    private final float[] mVerticesData2 =
            {
                    // positions          // colors           // texture coords
                    0.8f,  0.4f, 0.0f,   1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,  1.0f, 1.0f, // top right
                    0.8f, -0.4f, 0.0f,   0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,  1.0f, 0.0f, // bottom right
                    0.1f, -0.4f, 0.0f,   0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,  0.0f, 0.0f, // bottom left
                    0.1f,  0.4f, 0.0f,   1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,  0.0f, 1.0f  // top left

            };
      private final short[] mIndicesData =
            {
                    0, 1, 3 , 1, 2, 3
            };
    ShaderV1 Shaderprog1;
    private int[] VBOIds = new int[4]; // VertexBufferObject Ids
    private int[] VAOId = new int[2]; // VertexArrayObject Id
       private int mWidth;
    private int mHeight;
    private FloatBuffer mVertices;
    private ShortBuffer mIndices;
    private FloatBuffer mVertices2;

    public Renderer_Texture(Context context) {
        mVertices = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(mVerticesData.length * 4)
                .order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder()).asFloatBuffer();
        mVertices.put(mVerticesData).position(0);
        mVertices2 = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(mVerticesData2.length * 4)
                .order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder()).asFloatBuffer();
        mVertices2.put(mVerticesData2).position(0);
        mIndices = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(mIndicesData.length * 2)
                .order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder()).asShortBuffer();
        mIndices.put(mIndicesData).position(0);
    }

        private static Bitmap convertBitmapToConfig(Bitmap bitmap, Bitmap.Config config) {
            if (bitmap.getConfig() == config) {
                return bitmap;
            }
            Bitmap result = bitmap.copy(config, false);
            bitmap.recycle();
            return result;
        }

    public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 glUnused, EGLConfig config) {

        Shaderprog1= new ShaderV1("res/raw/vertext_shader1.vs", "res/raw/fragment_shader1.fs");

        GLES30.glGenBuffers(4, VBOIds, 0);
        GLES30.glBindBuffer(GLES30.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBOIds[0]);
        mVertices.position(0);
        GLES30.glBufferData(GLES30.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, mVerticesData.length * 4,
                mVertices, GLES30.GL_STATIC_DRAW);
        GLES30.glBindBuffer(GLES30.GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBOIds[1]);
        mIndices.position(0);
        GLES30.glBufferData(GLES30.GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 2 * mIndicesData.length,
                mIndices, GLES30.GL_STATIC_DRAW);

        GLES30.glBindBuffer(GLES30.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBOIds[2]);
        mVertices2.position(0);
        GLES30.glBufferData(GLES30.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, mVerticesData2.length * 4,
                mVertices2, GLES30.GL_STATIC_DRAW);

        GLES30.glGenVertexArrays(2, VAOId, 0);

        GLES30.glBindVertexArray(VAOId[0]);
        GLES30.glBindBuffer(GLES30.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBOIds[0]);
        GLES30.glBindBuffer(GLES30.GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBOIds[1]);
        GLES30.glEnableVertexAttribArray(VERTEX_POS_INDX);
        GLES30.glEnableVertexAttribArray(VERTEX_COLOR_INDX);
        GLES30.glEnableVertexAttribArray(VERTEX_TEXTUR_INDX);
        GLES30.glVertexAttribPointer(VERTEX_POS_INDX, VERTEX_POS_SIZE,
                GLES30.GL_FLOAT, false, VERTEX_STRIDE,
                0);
        GLES30.glVertexAttribPointer(VERTEX_COLOR_INDX, VERTEX_COLOR_SIZE,
                GLES30.GL_FLOAT, false, VERTEX_STRIDE,
                (VERTEX_POS_SIZE * 4));
        GLES30.glVertexAttribPointer(VERTEX_TEXTUR_INDX, VERTEX_TEXTUR_SIZE,
                GLES30.GL_FLOAT, false, VERTEX_STRIDE,
                (VERTEX_POS_SIZE * 4+VERTEX_COLOR_SIZE*4));
        //second:
        GLES30.glBindVertexArray(VAOId[1]);
        GLES30.glBindBuffer(GLES30.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBOIds[2]);
        GLES30.glBindBuffer(GLES30.GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBOIds[1]);
        GLES30.glEnableVertexAttribArray(VERTEX_POS_INDX);
        GLES30.glEnableVertexAttribArray(VERTEX_COLOR_INDX);
        GLES30.glEnableVertexAttribArray(VERTEX_TEXTUR_INDX);
        GLES30.glVertexAttribPointer(VERTEX_POS_INDX, VERTEX_POS_SIZE,
                GLES30.GL_FLOAT, false, VERTEX_STRIDE,
                0);
        GLES30.glVertexAttribPointer(VERTEX_COLOR_INDX, VERTEX_COLOR_SIZE,
                GLES30.GL_FLOAT, false, VERTEX_STRIDE,
                (VERTEX_POS_SIZE * 4));
        GLES30.glVertexAttribPointer(VERTEX_TEXTUR_INDX, VERTEX_TEXTUR_SIZE,
                GLES30.GL_FLOAT, false, VERTEX_STRIDE,
                (VERTEX_POS_SIZE * 4+VERTEX_COLOR_SIZE*4));
        // Reset to the default VAO
        GLES30.glBindVertexArray(0);

        GLES30.glClearColor(0.2f, 0.2f, 0.2f, 0.0f);

        GLES30.glGenTextures(2, textures,0);
        if (textures[0] == 0) {
           Log.e(TAG,"could not bind texture");
           return;
        }
        GLES30.glBindTexture(GLES30.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textures[0]);
        // set the texture wrapping parameters
        GLES30.glTexParameteri(GLES30.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES30.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GLES30.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
        GLES30.glTexParameteri(GLES30.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES30.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GLES30.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
        // set texture filtering parameters
        GLES30.glTexParameteri(GLES30.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES30.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GLES30.GL_LINEAR);
        GLES30.glTexParameteri(GLES30.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES30.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GLES30.GL_LINEAR);

            Bitmap bitmap = null;
            try {
                bitmap =convertBitmapToConfig(BitmapFactory.decodeStream(ShaderV1.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("res/raw/wall.jpg")), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
                ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(bitmap.getByteCount());
                bitmap.copyPixelsToBuffer(buffer);
                buffer.rewind();
                GLES30.glBindTexture(GLES30.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textures[0]);
                GLES30.glTexImage2D(GLES30.GL_TEXTURE_2D,0, GLES30.GL_RGB, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(),  0,  GLES30.GL_RGBA,  GLES30.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, buffer);
                //Log.e(TAG,"pixel "+ String.format("#%06X", (0xFFFFFF & bitmap.getPixel(200,200)))); //looks correct
                //Log.d(TAG,"bitmapsize:" + bitmap.getWidth() +" " + bitmap.getHeight()); //looks correct
                GLES30.glGenerateMipmap(GLES30.GL_TEXTURE_2D);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e(TAG,"texture error "+ e.getLocalizedMessage());
            } finally {
                if (bitmap != null) {
                    bitmap.recycle();
                }
            }
                byte[] bytes = {
            //  R           G            B      
                (byte) 0xcf,(byte) 0x00,(byte) 0x00,  //EDGE 1
                (byte) 0x8f,(byte) 0x00,(byte) 0x50,(byte) 0x00,(byte) 0x00, //EDGE 2 WTF 2 extra?!?
                (byte) 0x5f,(byte) 0x80,(byte) 0x00, //EDGE 3
                (byte) 0x3f,(byte) 0x00,(byte) 0x80}; //EDGE 4
        ByteBuffer b = ByteBuffer.wrap(bytes);

        GLES30.glBindTexture(GLES30.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textures[1]);
        GLES30.glTexParameteri(GLES30.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES30.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GLES30.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE); //GLES30.GL_REPEAT also work
        GLES30.glTexParameteri(GLES30.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES30.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GLES30.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE); //GLES30.GL_REPEAT also work
        // set texture filtering parameters
        GLES30.glTexParameteri(GLES30.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES30.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GLES30.GL_LINEAR);
        GLES30.glTexParameteri(GLES30.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES30.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GLES30.GL_LINEAR);

        GLES30.glTexImage2D ( GLES30.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GLES30.GL_RGB, 2, 2, 0, GLES30.GL_RGB, GLES30.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, b );
        GLES30.glGenerateMipmap(GLES30.GL_TEXTURE_2D);
            Shaderprog1.use();
        GLES30.glUniform1i(GLES30.glGetUniformLocation(Shaderprog1.getID(), "texture1"), 0);
    }

    public void onDrawFrame(GL10 glUnused) {
        GLES30.glViewport(0, 0, mWidth, mHeight);
        GLES30.glClear(GLES30.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        GLES30.glActiveTexture(GLES30.GL_TEXTURE0);
        GLES30.glBindTexture(GLES30.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textures[1]);
        Shaderprog1.use();

        GLES30.glBindVertexArray(VAOId[0]);
        GLES30.glDrawElements(GLES30.GL_TRIANGLES, mIndicesData.length, GLES30.GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0);
        GLES30.glBindTexture(GLES30.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textures[0]);
        GLES30.glBindVertexArray(VAOId[1]);
        GLES30.glDrawElements(GLES30.GL_TRIANGLES, mIndicesData.length, GLES30.GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0);

        GLES30.glBindVertexArray(0);
    }

    public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 glUnused, int width, int height) {
        mWidth = width;
        mHeight = height;
        Log.d ( TAG, width +" "+ height );
    }
}
```

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ruLnx.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android provides simple API for loading bitmap as OpenGL texture:

```
GLUtils.texImage2D(GLES30.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, bitmap, 0);
```

Edit: you can find more information about this here https://developer.android.com/reference/android/opengl/GLUtils#texImage2D(int,%20int,%20android.graphics.Bitmap,%20int)